# How can I infer generic type in kotlin? (covariance problem)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, covariance

I have two class which extends `Data`, interface.

```
A: Data
B: Data
```

Then I have two repositories. TestRepository is interface which get generic class.

```
TestRepository<T: Data> {
    fun save(data: T): T
}

@Repository
ARepository: TestRepository<A> {
    override fun save(data: A): A
}

@Repository
BRepository: TestRepository<B> {
    override fun save(data: B): B
}
```

it all have save method which gets data from generic type, and returns generic type.

ARepo and BRepo gets data from A: Data, B:Data and returns corresponding type.

Then we have new Service,

```
@Service
CService(
    private aRepository: ARepository,
    private bRepository: BRepository
) {
    fun test(t: String): TestRepository<out Data> =
        when (t) {
            '1' -> aRepository
            '2' -> bRepository
            else -> throw Error("error")
        }
    
}
```

it returns aRepository or bRepository, so return type of test function is `TestRepository<out Data>`. But when I try to use that class with DI,

```
@Service
class TestClass(
    private val cService: CService
) {

    fun cServiceTest() {

        ...
        val saveObject = Data('')
        val repo = cService.test("1") // or "2"
        repo.save(saveObject) <-- error

    }
}
```

repo.save emits error,

```
Type mismatch.
  Required:
    Nothing
  Found:
    Data
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: What does the Save function return? Whatever the parameter was, for chaining?

Comment: It returns out T, just think it returns itself.

Comment: I don’t see any way this can logically make sense. When you get a repository back from the `test` function, there’s no way to know what type of Data you’re allowed to pass to it. And the `saveObject` you created in your test code isn’t a valid input for either of your repository types because it’s not an A or a B.

Comment: in reality, `saveObject` will be either A or B. Also return repo of cService.test will get A or B (Corresponding saveObject type). I know computer have no way to infer it, so I want to make sure repo would save A if it is instantiated by '1' (ARepo), or save B if it is instantiated by '2' (BRepo)

Answer (score 0):

**How about this?**

---

`import kotlin.reflect.KClass`

```kotlin
interface Data {
    val name: String
}

data class A(
    override val name: String = "A"
) : Data

data class B(
    override val name: String = "B"
) : Data

interface DataRepository<T : Data> {
    fun save(data: T): T
}

class ARepository : DataRepository<A> {
    override fun save(data: A): A {
        println("Saved - (A)")
        return data.copy()
    }
}

class BRepository : DataRepository<B> {
    override fun save(data: B): B {
        println("Saved - (B)")
        return data.copy()
    }
}

class DataService(
    private val aClassRepository: ARepository = ARepository(),
    private val bClassRepository: BRepository = BRepository(),
) {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun <T : Data> getRepository(_class: KClass<T>): DataRepository<T> =
        when (_class) {
            A::class -> aClassRepository
            B::class -> bClassRepository
            else -> throw RuntimeException()
        } as? DataRepository<T> ?: throw RuntimeException()
}

fun main() {
    val service = DataService()
    val repository = service.getRepository(A::class)
    val saved = repository.save(A())
    println(saved)
}
```

I don't know what kind of problem you are trying to solve.

So I think the solution I came up with is not good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).